# iOS design PNG files

Tags: iphone, ios, photoshop

I have just started designing for my first iOS app and I am confused to which type of .PNG of file I need to use or if it matters at all. I am using Photoshop and Illustrator to make my images. Do I "Save for web and devices" as a PNG-24? Or do I "Save As" a .PNG? I have looked a lot of places and can't find much documentation.

Comment: shortly: at the _Save for Web and Devices_ the `PNG-24` with `transparency` will be perfect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a resource for you:

http://bjango.com/articles/pngcompression/

To make it short:

> For all images and icons, the PNG format is recommended (avoid using
>   interlaced PNGs). The standard bit depth for icons and images is 24
>   bits (8 bits each for red, green, and blue), plus an 8-bit alpha
>   channel. You do not need to constrain your palette to web-safe colors.
>   Although you can use alpha transparency in the icons you create for
>   navigation bars, toolbars, and tab bars, do not use it in application
>   icons.